# Changing values of a specific column within a range

Tags: vba, excel

I want to set the values of a column within the current selected range. For example, the current selected range (which could vary) is A5:D10, I want the values in column B of the range to be "Something". I'm guessing it would be something like:

```
ActiveCell.Columns("B").Value="Something"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also use the `Intersect()` function...

```
Sub Intersection_Example()

    Dim rngB As Range
    Dim rngResult As Range

    Set rngB = Columns("B")
    Set rngResult = Intersect(Selection, rngB)

    rngResult.Value = "Something"

End Sub
```